# Evaluation of $\sum^{\infty} _{n=1} \arctan\left(\frac{4n}{n^4-2n^2+2}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

> Evaluate $\displaystyle\sum^{\infty} _{n=1} \arctan\left(\frac{4n}{n^4-2n^2+2}\right).$

I know we know to convert it in the of $\arctan\left(\frac{a-b}{1+ab}\right)$ but I am not able to do so here.

Could someone give me some hint?

Comment: $n^4 - 2n^2 + 2 = 1 + (n^2-1)^2$ may be useful.

Comment: The answer appears to be $3\pi/4$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes $3\pi/4$ is in the options.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint**. One may write, for $n\ge2$,
$$
\frac{4n}{n^4-2n^2+2}=\frac{4n}{(n^2-1)^2+1}=\frac{\frac{4n}{(n^2-1)^2}}{1+\frac1{(n^2-1)^2}}=\frac{\frac1{(n-1)^2}-\frac1{(n+1)^2}}{1+\frac1{(n-1)^2(n+1)^2}}
$$ giving here
$$
\arctan\frac{4n}{n^4-2n^2+2}=\arctan\frac1{(n-1)^2}-\arctan\frac1{(n+1)^2}.
$$

Comment: Great answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\dfrac{4n}{n^4-2n^2+2}=\dfrac{(n+1)^2-(n-1)^2}{1+(n^2-1)^2}$$

$$\implies\arctan\dfrac{4n}{n^4-2n^2+2}=\arctan\{(n+1)^2\}-\arctan\{(n-1)^2\}=f(n+1)-f(n-1)$$

where $f(m)=\arctan(m^2)$