# Limit and sequence involving tangent

Tags: limits, trigonometry, summation

> Find the value of $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{r=2}^n\left(\cot\left(S_{r-1}\right) -\cot\left(S_r \right)\right)$$
>   where  $$S_n=\sum_{r=1}^n \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{2\left(2r-1\right)}{4+r^2\left(r^2 -2r + 1\right)}\right)$$

**My work**

I tried to convert into $$\tan^{-1}A - \tan^{-1}B$$
$$\tan^{-1}\left( \frac{\frac{\left(2r-1\right)}{2}}{1+\frac{r^2\left(r -1\right)^2}{4}}\right)$$

But it was unsuccessful I was not able to find it in this form .

Comment: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{r=2}^n\left(\cot\left(S_{r-1}\right) -\cot\left(S_r \right)\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\cot(S_1)-\cot(S_n)$

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870756/evaluation-of-sum-infty-n-1-tan-1-frac4nn4-2n22

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a_r=\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac {r^2}2\right)$.

$\displaystyle a_r-a_{r-1}=\tan^{-1}\left( \frac{2\left(2r-1\right)}{4+r^2\left(r^2 -2r + 1\right)}\right)$

Therefore, $S_n$, like the limit you are trying to find, are just a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: Well done!  A +1.

Comment: How did you know how to do this? Is this a known substitution? Or did you try to change it into a telescoping series intentionally?

Comment: @user51819 I tried to change it into a telescoping series intentionally after noticing that the thing inside the arctangent highly resembles some form of $\tan^{-1}X-\tan^{-1}Y$.

Comment: @KennyLau Is the answer 2